# Behringer Pro Mixer DX 500 Needs to match new power supply adapter

Tags: power-supply

I'm quite unfamiliar with the electrical side of things, so I'd appreciate it a lot if I can get some basic help.

I have a Behringer Pro Mixer DX 500 at home which would be used mostly in Bulgaria - where the voltage is at 220V. It came without a power supply adapter, in the photo (where it's a bit blurry) it says:

**POWER SORCE: 2 * 19 VAC 30W**

Here's also the manual for the mixer if it's helpful:
https://manualzz.com/doc/29044519/pro-mixer-dx500

[image]

Turned out a power supply adapter is close to impossible to find quickly on the web and in a bit of a rush, I purchased the following from the US:

[image]

The model (which is cropped out in the picture) is MXUL2 specifically.

Only later I realized it says **2 * 17.5 VAC**.

So I wanted to ask if that's gonna be in any way a problem and, in case it is, can I somehow compensate by purchasing a precise Down Voltage Transformer (which I need to get anyway for transforming 220 V to 115V)?

Even if the **2 * 17.5 VAC** discrepancy wouldn't be a problem (I so hope it wouldn't), feel free to suggest a respective Down Voltage Transformer, if you have something in mind that is a good choice on the low price end of things.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Questions on the *usage* of products are not on topic here.  It might work are reduced performance, it might not - it depends on information not available to you, which would be needed to support an on-topic question here.  Really the only way to know is to ask the manufacturer, or perhaps do some web searching and find an audio *forum* where users of this product share experiences and product-unique knowledge.

Comment: No, you cannot use that transformer.   It's designed for 110V AC  input.  Where you live, the voltage is 220.   If you use that transformer, it will output double the specified voltage  (i.e. about 35V).   You'll almost surely blow your equipment.

Comment: Probably will work fine, you can also get an allegedly "Made in Russia" toroidal transformer model from central Asia (or maybe China) for about $50. that has the proper voltage/frequency/line cord for beautiful Bulgaria.

Comment: FWIW I do not believe that this is a "duplicate" but rather an off topic *usage* question.  Assuming the input voltage issue is worked out with a step-down, what is unknowable is how the product will react to 17.5 volts vs the intended 19 volts (or more correctly, twice those with centertaps).  Many op-amp type things could work but would have slightly reduced performance, but we really don't know what's in the box.

Comment: Strange, the manual says the MXUL2 is the PSU to use for this deck in the USA, but it also says it outputs 2 x 18.5V. The one you have says it outputs 2 x 17.5V. You would need to ask Behringer to clear that up. Going from 230V to 115V requires a step-down transformer. I doubt the deck will mind getting 50Hz instead of 60Hz AC, not entirely sure though.